# Telegraf multiple nginx in a single host

Tags: telegraf

I have 3 Nginx servers running on a single host and have a diffuculty to set up correctly in Telegraf. Here is the current setup for one Nginx server and need to add two inputs which are for  decoding log files for other two servers. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#nginx-metrics and logs
[[inputs.nginx]]
   urls = ["https://example.com/nginx_status"]
   response_timeout = "5s"

[[inputs.tail]]
   name_override = "nginxlog"
   files = ["/var/www/example/logs/http-access.log"]
   from_beginning = false
   pipe = false
   data_format = "grok"
   grok_patterns = ["%{COMBINED_LOG_FORMAT}"]

[[inputs.exec]]
   commands = [
    "sh /etc/telegraf/nginx_stats.sh"
   ]
   timeout = "5s"
   name_override = "nginx_response_code"
   data_format = "json"
   tag_keys = [
     "resp_code"
   ]

[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
    listen = "0.0.0.0:9125"
```

For example, something like this.

```
[[inputs.tail]]
    name_override = "nginxlog"
    files = ["/var/www/example2/logs/http-access.log"]
    from_beginning = false
    pipe = false
    data_format = "grok"
    grok_patterns = ["%{COMBINED_LOG_FORMAT}"]

[[inputs.exec]]
    commands = [
     "sh /etc/telegraf/nginx_stats2.sh"
  ]
  timeout = "5s"
  name_override = "nginx_response_code"
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [
    "resp_code"
  ]



[[inputs.tail]]
    name_override = "nginxlog"
    files = ["/var/www/example3/logs/http-access.log"]
    from_beginning = false
    pipe = false
    data_format = "grok"
    grok_patterns = ["%{COMBINED_LOG_FORMAT}"]

[[inputs.exec]]
    commands = [
     "sh /etc/telegraf/nginx_stats3.sh"
  ]
  timeout = "5s"
  name_override = "nginx_response_code"
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [
    "resp_code"
  ]
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide some additional details as to what is complicated or preventing you from continuing to expand your second example with a third server?

Comment: Hi! As you could see, there is three log files from three different vhost, example, example2, example 3. Based on my config there is no way to know which nginx reponse code came from which vhost because they are all in one single host. Or did I miunderstand it?